# one way works and the other does not

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file that displays a random pic. one way the code works fine and the other way it does not work (does not display any pic). the following code is the code that works and the code that does not work.

This code WORKS:

```
<script> selectdir = 0; var SBcount = 1; </script>

<script src="js/scripts/superbook.js"> </script>

<script> document.write(textSB); textSB = ''; </script>

<script> selectdir = 0; var SBcount = 2; </script>

<script src="js/scripts/superbook.js"> </script>

<script> document.write(textSB); textSB = ''; </script>

<script> selectdir = 0; var SBcount = 3; </script>

<script src="js/scripts/superbook.js"> </script>

<script> document.write(textSB); textSB = ''; </script>

<script> selectdir = 0; var SBcount = 4; </script>

<script src="js/scripts/superbook.js"> </script>

<script> document.write(textSB); textSB = ''; </script>
```

---

this code does NOT work:

```
<script>
 var SBcount = 0;

 for (SBcharcount = 1; SBcharcount < 5; SBcharcount++)
     {
       var selectdir = 0; var SBcount++;
       document.write('<scr' + 'ipt language="javascript" src="' +      
       loveisdomaindir + 'js/scripts/superbook.js"> <\/script>');
       document.write(textSB); textSB = '';
     }
</script>
```

this code is inside superbook.js, where SBcount is used:

```
switch (SBcount)
       {
         case  1 : SBtop = 225; SBleft = 1275; SBheight = 145;
                   SBwidth = 100; break;

         case  2 : SBtop = 325; SBleft = 1425; SBheight = 145;
                   SBwidth = 100; break;
         case  3 : SBtop = 770; SBleft = 725;  SBheight = 145;
                   SBwidth = 100; break;
         case  4 : SBtop = 625; SBleft = 1300; SBheight = 145;
                   SBwidth = 100; break;
         case  5 : SBtop = 12;  SBleft = 210;  SBheight = 50;
                   SBwidth = 50; break;
         case  6 : SBtop = 345; SBleft = 210;  SBheight = 50;
                   SBwidth = 50; break;
         case  7 : SBtop = 515; SBleft = 210;  SBheight = 50;
                   SBwidth = 50; break;
         default : SBtop = 225; SBleft = 1275; SBheight = 145;
                   SBwidth = 100; break;
   }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Define "works" and "does not work".

Comment: 'works' is it displays the pic as it is supposed to. 'does not work' is that it displays nothing, no pic.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `var SBcount++` is a syntax error. You can't declare a variable and increment it at the same time.

That said, you have a fundamental flaw with the approach you are taking.

When you use `document.write` to write to the document stream, it inserts the script elements *after* the current script element.

They won't get executed until the first script element has finished executing.

So if you have a script (a) which:

1. Set X to 1
2. Generate a script (b) which writes X
3. Set X to 2
4. Generate a script (c) which writes X

Then the events happen in this order:

1. X is 1
2. X is 2
3. Script b writes 2
4. Script c writes 2

If you want step 2 to happen after step 3, then you need to generate a whole separate script element to change the value of X (just like you did by hand in your first code example)

---

But **don't do that**. Replace `superbook.js` with a **function** and then call it multiple times (passing values as arguments).